Lexical text editor Find editor state
I have installed the lexical rich text editor, I have an interesting situation from the lexical playground, lexical works without problems in the dev branch, but in the staging branch
"Error: Unable to find an active editor state. State helpers or node methods can only be used synchronously during the callback of editor.update() or editorState.read()."
so it gives an error, the package and codes are the same
Rechecking packages version and code version
